# Hamburger menu | How to change the icon to X when expanded

Tags: mobile, drop-down-menu, hamburger-menu

I am looking to change the hamburger menu to an X when the mobile menu is expanded. How do I do this? Thank you in advance!

Below is a link to what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/lgruter/pen/JjmvNGG

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
    

}
```